# Directive not executing corretcly on route change

Tags: angularjs

I have directive in angular to add fixed to top class every time user scrolls a bit, to have sticky header with some basic info . Directive goes as following:

```
app.directive('fixedTop', function ($window) {
    var $win = angular.element($window);
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           $log.debug("fixedTop init");
           var topClass = attrs.fixedTop;
           var containerClass = 'container';
           var offsetTop = element.offset().top;
           $win.on('scroll', function (e) {
                if ($win.scrollTop() >= offsetTop) {
                    element.addClass(topClass);
                    element.children().first().addClass(containerClass);
                    $log.debug("fixedTop add topClass");                        
                } else {
                    element.removeClass(topClass);
                    element.children().first().removeClass(containerClass);
                    $log.debug("fixedTop remove topClass");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My route is defined without any custom addons like this:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'home'
        })
        //rest of routes
```

Index html :

```
<div class="row" id="main-ccontent">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 main">
        <div ng-view="" class="container main-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One of two templates which use directive starts with following:

```
<div class="row header-fixed animate-appear" fixed-top="fix-to-top">
    <!--      Header       -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```

It works nice as it should, problem is that , whenever I change route ( go to other sub-page ) my directive is not working , and I have to execute page refresh (F5) to make it work again.

So I suppose it have something to do how route works and when directives are rendered or something like this?

**UPDATE**: After adding logging , on first load when I scroll. in console logs:

```
fixedTop init
(times 6 ) fixedTop remove topClass
(times 38) fixedTop add topClass
```

But when I navigate to another route I have:

```
fixedTop init
(times 6 ) fixedTop remove topClass
fixedTop add topClass
fixedTop remove topClass
fixedTop add topClass
fixedTop remove topClass
fixedTop add topClass
fixedTop remove topClass
fixedTop add topClass
fixedTop remove topClass
fixedTop add topClass
fixedTop remove topClass
```

.. and so on so on...
So it seems like on route change , it's switching it on and off

**UPDATE 2** Added scrollTop and offset debug:

```
            $log.debug(offsetTop);
            $log.debug($win.scrollTop());
```

And on route change result is

```
fixedTop init
70
91.81817626953125
fixedTop add topClass
1316.3635711669922
91.81817626953125
fixedTop remove topClass
70
96.36363220214844
fixedTop add topClass
1316.3635711669922
96.36363220214844
fixedTop remove topClass
```

This is happening on route change only. Whenever I enter page normally , directive has correct offset value

Comment: Did you test it? Put console.log in scroll listener function, and in intialization function. And look how many times Init function called, and is onscroll function working

Comment: it's hard to diagnose this without a [mcve], but since your directive references a `'container'` class, but that class doesn't appear to be in the HTML you show, I might *guess* that it is in the `home.html`.  when the route changes, that element is replaced with some other element, and the directive has nothing to operate on any longer.

Comment: @Leguest I added logging and updated my question.

Comment: @Claies Directive is already in container. As header is set as position:fixed, it needs extra container to align contents. And everything works until template is changed with route. Updated structure in original question

Comment: It seems like something with your if logic, you need to check in console.log offsetTop and  $win.scrollTop()

Comment: Updated question, offset of element value is very wrong on route enter :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After while I came back to this.
The root cause was that on ng-route change contents were dynamic and

element.offset().top

Was with wrong value when elements were re-rendered.
To fix I based on answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30380846/1254412
, where is detailed explanation why my original approach was erronous

The final directive is now working if element is wrapped in empty div and with following code

```
app.directive('fixedTop', function ($window, $log) {
var $win = angular.element($window);
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var topClass = attrs.fixedTop;
        var containerClass = 'container';
        var parent = element.parent();
        $win.on('scroll', function (e) {
            var offsetTop = parent.offset().top;
            if ($win.scrollTop() >= offsetTop) {
                element.addClass(topClass);
                element.children().first().addClass(containerClass);
                parent.height(element.height());
            } else {
                element.removeClass(topClass);
                element.children().first().removeClass(containerClass);
                parent.css("height", null);
            }
          });
        }
    }
});
```

usage:

```
<div>
    <div class="row header-fixed animate-appear" fixed-top="fix-to-top">
    <!--  contents -->
    </div>
<div>
```